# MKMapView cached tiles

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, mkmapview

I need to clear the cached tiles stored by the device every time I load a new region does anyone know how to do this?

Many thanks

Jules

Answer (score 0):

`MKMapView` uses `NSURLConnection` to get data from network. Given that, one thing you can do, is set the cache size to 0, which will make the connection to alway go to the server and update the data.

```
 NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
[sharedCache release];
```